# Como executar duas funções da mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tenho essa function para agrupar valores de duas tabelas "vendas" e "clientes", mas além de agrupar essas informações, preciso executar uma busca no banco conforme os parâmetros. Não consigo unir as duas, executo apenas uma de cada vez. Como fazer?

```
function getVendas()
{
$this->db->select('vendas.*, clientes.nomeCliente');
    $this->db->from('vendas');
    $this->db->join('clientes', 'clientes.idClientes = vendas.clientes_id');      
    $this->db->limit(10);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}



 function getVendas()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE dataVenda BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-7 AND CURRENT_DATE() AND faturado = 0";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
}
```

Comment: Qua o nome da engine de DB e qual o nome da lib de acesso DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na primeira query em que estás a usar o query builder podes simplesmente adicionar a tua pesquisa.

```
public function getVendas()
{
    $this->db->select('vendas.*, clientes.nomeCliente');
    $this->db->from('vendas');
    $this->db->join('clientes', 'clientes.idClientes = vendas.clientes_id');      
    $this->db->where('vendas.dataVenda BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-7 AND CURRENT_DATE()', null, false);
    $this->db->where('vendas.faturado', 0);
    $this->db->limit(10);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Desta forma estás a fazer logo a pesquisa no teu join.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado.